# Error while installing mobsf on mac

Tags: security, mobile, frameworks

This error is occuring again and again while installing mobsf on mac----->

c -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/_openssl.o -Wconversion -Wno-error=sign-conversion
    build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/_openssl.c:493:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
    #include 
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/9t/_bpw_6gx4vjb2yh1207xkhbw0000gn/T/pip-install-r2zcxnqo/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/9t/_bpw_6gx4vjb2yh1207xkhbw0000gn/T/pip-record-qjxlvc64/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9t/_bpw_6gx4vjb2yh1207xkhbw0000gn/T/pip-install-r2zcxnqo/cryptography/

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? What commands do you run that cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of MobSF and it's recommendation for installation in its [GitHub page](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) (because it's continuously getting updated).